# How to resize VSTS dashboard widget

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am building a VSTS team dashboard widget and I would like to display some custom html content; however the default widget size is very small and part of the html gets cut off. Refer to the following screenshot:

[image: I would like the window to at least be a fixed length in the horizontal and perhaps a dynamic vertical.]

> How can I resize the widget so that the widget is larger in area?

**Note**: I tried adding some CSS to the div of widget but that only changed the width that was "inside" the widget container, and thus it didn't make the widget outline bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget size can be defined in manifest file like vss-extension.json.

Under vss-extension.json `contributions` oject, you can define the `supportedSizes` as a contribution's property.
Such as below is a piece of the vss-extension.json file defined with multiple sizes:

```
{
        "id": "HelloWorldWidget3",
        "type": "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget",
        "targets": [
            "ms.vss-dashboards-web.widget-catalog",
            ".HelloWorldWidget.Configuration"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "Hello World Widget 3 (with config)",
            "description": "My third widget which supports configuration.",
            "catalogIconUrl": "img/helloWorld.png",
            "previewImageUrl": "img/helloWorld_330x160.png",
            "uri": "hello-world3.html",
          "supportedSizes": [
            {
              "rowSpan": 1,
              "columnSpan": 2
            },
            {
              "rowSpan": 2,
              "columnSpan": 2
            },
            {
              "rowSpan": 3,
              "columnSpan": 2
            },
            {
              "rowSpan": 4,
              "columnSpan": 2
            }
          ],
            "supportedScopes": [
                "project_team"
            ]
        }
}
```

More details, you can refer the [example widget extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/widgets) with Hello World Widget 3 (with config). And you can define more sizes under the `supportedSizes` (as above example).

**Note:** you also need to specify the configuration under the targets. As the `".HelloWorldWidget.Configuration"` for above example.

Answer (score 0):

Some widgets are pre-sized and can't be changed. Others are configurable through their configuration dialog. [Widget Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/add-widget-to-dashboard?view=vsts&tabs=new-query-exp#widget-size)

> Prerequisites
>
> - You must be a member of a team project. If you don't have a team
>   project yet, create one in VSTS.
> - If you haven't been added as a team member, get added now.
> - Anyone with access to the team project, including stakeholders, can
>   view dashboards.
> - To add, edit, or manage a team dashboard, you must be a team admin, a
>   project admin, or have dashboard permissions. In general, you need to
>   be a team admin for the currently selected team to edit dashboards.
>   Request your current team or project admin to add you as a team
>   admin.

*You'll need to turn on preview features first if they're not enabled already* [Enable Preview Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/preview-features?view=vsts)

Comment: So there is no way of dynamically changing the rowSpan for example in the vss-extension.json through code? Because apparently if you want the area of the widget to be bigger you can set that in the properties object in the Contributions array but this will be a static size.

Comment: You are correct. The vss-extension.json configuration file can be used to statically define a rowSpan value but not dynamically.